# Cocoa Binding to NSTableView selection

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a Mac Os X Xcode project with a View based `NSTableView` which displays a list of file paths. The `NSTableView` is populated by bindings to a `NSArrayController` in the `MainMenu.xib` file, the `NSArrayController` is bound to a `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionaries`, each with a `thePath` key in it containing the file path. Everything works as expected. Now I want to put a `NSPathControl` below the `NSTableView` to show the path of the selected file in the `NSTableView`. The `NSPathControl` should be hidden if there is no row selected in the `NSTableView`. How can I configure the `NSPathControl` bindings to make it disappear when there is no selection and make it show the correct file path when a row is selected in the `NSTableView` ? I am a bit confused about binding to `NSArrayController` `selectionIndexes` thanks any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only need one selection bind to NSArrayController's selection instead. When multiple or nothing is selected it will return NSNull which the NSPathControl will display as blank.

Comment: Actually, if there are multiple selections, the binding will produce `NSMultipleValuesMarker`. When there's no selection, it will produce `NSNoSelectionMarker`. But it does seem that it will be effectively invisible for either of those. If you really want to make sure, bind the path control's Hidden binding to the array controller, controller key `selection`, model key path `@count`, transformer `NSNegateBoolean`.

Comment: Thanks a lot geowar, in the meanwhile I have discovered the problem I was having, trying to bind to NSInteger key paths, but now I have discovered they are automatically included in a NSNumber instance. Thanks again